# App.config и приложение на C#

Tags: c#, .net, config, clr

У меня есть небольшая программа на 2 версии .NET, но новых версиях Windows  она не запускается, но если создать файл настроек, то она запустится.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0"/>
  <supportedRuntime version="v3.5"/>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Есть какие-нибудь варианты, что можно сделать, чтоб было не 2 файла, а 1? Т.е внедрить этот файл настроек в exe или ещё как-нибудь.

Comment: Судя по [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315155/can-i-specify-supportedruntime-or-any-other-config-parameter-without-a-config) из кода это сделать нельзя. Ну а вообще, `.net 2`, вы серьезно?! Зачем так издеваться над собой?

Comment: на старых компах может быть не установлен .NET 4, приходится использовать 2 версию

Comment: .NET 4 ставится на XP, куда ещё старее?

Comment: Напишите неуправляемое приложение на С++, которое будет из себя распаковывать программу на C# и конфиг во временную папку и запускать.

Comment: ПКМ по файлу *.exe => "Свойства" => "Совместимость" / "Запуск в режиме совместимости:" и хоть "Win95", например :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встроить файл конфигурации в EXE-файл нельзя (так как весь смысл конфигурации - это возможность редактирования параметров без перекомпиляции программы, такой возможности не предусмотрели). Влиять на параметр `supportedRuntime` из кода на C# также нельзя, так этот параметр используется неуправляемым кодом загрузчика до того, как в процесс загружена CLR, и в этот момент управляемый код еще не может выполняться.

Если нужно управлять выбором версии CLR без файла конфигурации, единственный способ - написать свой собственный загрузчик на С++, пользуясь [Unmanaged .NET API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/index).

Например, создадим такую программу на C#:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Run(string arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from .NET " + Environment.Version.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run("");
        }        
    }    
}
```

Скомпилируем ее, получаем файл *Program.exe*. Создадим проект С++, добавим в него файл *Program.exe* и создадим файл ресурсов *resource.rc* следующего содержания:

```
#define IDR_RCDATA1 101

IDR_RCDATA1 RCDATA "Program.exe"
```

Напишем на С++ код загрузчика, который находит первую установленную версию CLR, загружает ее, извлекает из ресурсов программу на C# во временную папку и запускает ее:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <metahost.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mscoree.lib")

#define IDR_RCDATA1 101

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    LPCWSTR prog_name = L"Program.exe"; //имя программы на C#

    //построим путь к временному файлу  
    WCHAR temppath[300] = L"c:\\temp\\";
    GetTempPath(300,temppath);
    wcscat(temppath,prog_name); 

    //извлечем программу из ресурсов
    HRSRC myResource = ::FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_RCDATA1), RT_RCDATA);
    UINT Size = ::SizeofResource(NULL, myResource);
    HGLOBAL myResourceData = ::LoadResource(NULL, myResource);
    void* pMyBinaryData = ::LockResource(myResourceData);
    FILE* f = _wfopen(temppath,L"wb");
    fwrite(pMyBinaryData,Size,1,f);
    fclose(f);

    //инициализация CLR...
    HRESULT hr;
    ICLRMetaHost *pMetaHost = NULL;
    ICLRRuntimeInfo *pRuntimeInfo = NULL;
    ICLRRuntimeHost *pClrRuntimeHost = NULL; 
    IEnumUnknown* pEnum= NULL;
    ICLRRuntimeInfo* pInfo= NULL;
    IUnknown* pUnk = NULL;

    hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMetaHost));
    if(FAILED(hr)){printf("CLRCreateInstance failed\n");goto End;}

    //поиск установленных версий CLR...
    pMetaHost->EnumerateInstalledRuntimes(&pEnum);
    if(FAILED(hr)){printf("EnumerateInstalledRuntimes failed\n");goto End;}

    ULONG c= 0;
    WCHAR buffer[250];
    DWORD cch = 250;

    while(1){
        if(pInfo!=NULL){pInfo->Release();pInfo = NULL;}
        if(pUnk!=NULL){pUnk->Release();pUnk = NULL;}
        if(pRuntimeInfo!=NULL){pRuntimeInfo->Release();pRuntimeInfo = NULL;}        

        hr = pEnum->Next(1,&pUnk,&c);
        if(hr != S_OK)break;

        pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_ICLRRuntimeInfo, (void**)&pInfo);
        if(FAILED(hr)){printf("QueryInterface failed\n");continue;}

        pInfo->GetVersionString(buffer,&cch);
        if(FAILED(hr)){printf("GetVersionString failed\n");continue;}

        hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime(buffer, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo));
        if(hr == S_OK){break;}      
        else {wprintf(L".NET %s: GetRuntime HRESULT 0x%x\n",buffer,(UINT)hr);}
    }

    if(pRuntimeInfo == NULL){printf("Failed to initialize CLR\n");goto End;}

    /* Можно также указать версию явно, например:
          pMetaHost->GetRuntime(L"v2.0.50727", IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo));
          pMetaHost->GetRuntime(L"v4.0.30319", IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo));
       и т.п.
    */

    hr = pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&pClrRuntimeHost));
    if(FAILED(hr)){printf("GetInterface failed\n");goto End;}

    //запуск CLR
    hr = pClrRuntimeHost->Start();
    if(FAILED(hr)){printf("Start failed\n");goto End;}

    //Запуск программы на C#
    DWORD pReturnValue;
    hr = pClrRuntimeHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(
        temppath,
        L"ConsoleApplication1.Program", //класс
        L"Run", //метод
        L"", //параметр
        &pReturnValue);
    if(FAILED(hr)){printf("ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain failed 0x%x\n",(UINT)hr);goto End;}

End:

    //Освобождение ресурсов
    if(pMetaHost != NULL) pMetaHost->Release();
    if(pRuntimeInfo != NULL) pRuntimeInfo->Release();
    if(pClrRuntimeHost != NULL) pClrRuntimeHost->Release();
    if(pEnum != NULL) pEnum->Release();
    if(pInfo != NULL) pInfo->Release();
    if(pUnk != NULL) pUnk->Release();       
    return 0;
}
```

В результате программа, собранная под .NET 2.0, при его отсутствии будет запускаться на имеющейся версии .NET, как и при использовании параметра `supportedRuntime`.

**Источники:**

[Embedding supportedRuntime into exe file - ответ Ondrej Svejdar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45056961/8674428)

[How to load a custom binary resource in a VC++ static library as part of a dll?
 - ответ LihO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240388/8674428)