# Как создать единый exe-файл без app.dll.config?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, exe, visual-studio-2022

Несмотря на выбор "Создать отдельный файл" в параметрах профиля публикации, в результате всё равно VS рядом с `appName.exe` создаёт файлы `appName.dll.config` и `appName.pdb`. И если pdb-файл, как я понимаю, нужен только для отладки и может быть спокойно удалён, то без config-файла приложение работать не будет.

`appName.dll.config` был создан автоматически и хранит информацию с первоначальными настройками, установленными мной в `Properties.Settings`.

Так как всё-таки перенести config в exe? Или изменить способ хранения настроек, чтобы не требовались дополнительные файлы вовсе?

[image: Параметры профиля]

[image: Результат]

Comment: Никак и незачем: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823677/ Перепишите программу, чтобы она не использовала XML-конфигурацию, тогда файл можно будет удалить. Кстати вы проверяли, что она работает для self-contained публикации (т.е. если поменять значения в .config, они подхватываются в программе)? Этот тип конфигурации устаревший, вполне возможно, что при такой схеме программа его не увидит.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Не совсем вас понимаю. Как не использовать XML-конфигурацию, если она создаётся автоматически? Вовсе не использовать `Properties.Settings`? Я вообще плохо понимаю зачем нужен этот файл, ведь в дополнение к нему в папке AppData создаётся файл `user.config` с текущими настройками, изменяющимися во время работы приложения. А изменение `appName.dll.config` ни на что не влияет. Если XML-конфигурация устарела, то чем её можно заменить?

Comment: `appName.dll.config` нужен для свойств, у которых задана область приложения, а не пользователя. Если у вас таких свойств нет, этот файл создается впустую, и его можно удалить (ну, точнее, не передавать его пользователю вместе с приложением). Он создается автоматически только из-за того, что этого требует шаблон.

Comment: Заменить можно на [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration), но он главным образом для параметров, которые не изменяются пользователем. Если вы используете параметры области пользователя, скорее всего, лучше оставить XML-конфигурацию (без appName.dll.config, но с использованием конфига из AppData, он будет работать).

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Так в том-то и дело, что все свойства имеют область пользователя, но при удалении `appName.dll.config` приложение не запускается. Вообще, у меня в данный момент есть сразу 3 config-файла с примерно одинаковым содержимым: `App.config` - внутри проекта, `appName.dll.config` - создаётся рядом с exe-файлом и не меняется после публикации, и `user.config` в AppData, который собственно и занимается делом. Это нормально?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Что касается, _Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration_, как я понимаю, он работает только на чтение и не подходит для хранения состояния окна между сессиями (размер, положение etc)?

Comment: Это нормально, но должен быть способ избавиться от `appName.dll.config`. Без него программа вообще не запускается, или падает с ошибкой? В журнале событий не появляется запись о необработанном исключении? "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, как я понимаю, он работает только на чтение" - Да, только на чтение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за советы. Проблему решило удаление файла `user.config` в AppData, оставшегося от предыдущей публикации. После этого удаление `appName.dll.config` не мешает работе приложения.

Answer (score 2):

При необходимости конфигурацию "зашить" в исполняемый файл, для этого в файле проекта нужно добавить следующие строчки:

```xml
    <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
      <Exec Command="copy $(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).dll.config $(ProjectDir)\$(TargetName).dll.config" />
    </Target>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="appName.dll.config" />
        <EmbeddedResource Include="appName.dll.config">
            <LogicalName>appName.dll.config</LogicalName>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Содержимое файла можно получить например вот через такую функцию:

```
    public static string LoadDllConfig()
    {
        var assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.All.SelectMany(alc => alc.Assemblies).Single(asm => asm.GetManifestResourceNames().Any(resourceName => resourceName.EndsWith(".dll.config")));
        var resourceName = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Single(resourceName => resourceName.EndsWith(".dll.config"));
        using var streamReader = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)!);
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: А смысл? Конфигурация нужна, чтобы данные не были прошиты в коде и их можно было изменить без пересборки. Если ее запихать ресурсы, это все равно, что не использовать конфигурацию. Можно просто присвоить переменным начальные значения в коде и удалить .config.